# Android onItemSelected Spinner not activating

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

My application is not initiating the onItemSelected method, when I change my spinner view.
It should work fine, but it is not functioning.

```
class UnitConverter extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    Spinner spinner, spinner2;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter, kilogramAdapter, metreAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_converter, container, false);
        spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.SI_spinner);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.si_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        metreAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.metre_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        metreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        kilogramAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.kilogram_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        kilogramAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2.setAdapter(metreAdapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
        spinner2.setAdapter(kilogramAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the listener with your spinner like below code

if you are implementing the `OnItemSelectedListener` like you are doing in the code provided by you. then register the listener like this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

or if you are creating a new class implementing the `OnItemSelectedListener` interface.

then you can register that class with your spinner view like this

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyCustomListener());


private class MyCustomListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
        // Write your logic what you want to do on selecting the item
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Spinner` Item selected `Listener`

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you going to use `Listview` or `Spinner`,you want to fire the selection use below code

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```